# Hashing password algorith issue

Tags: c#, mysql, hash

I am new in C# wpf programming but I am trying to connect to MySQL database and to hash my password. Unfortunately while I was implementing the algorith I get error in this code:

```
byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
salt.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
plainText.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length);
```

The error is:

```
Error: no overload for method 'Copy To' takes 2 arguments Exceptions: System.ArgumentNullException System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
enter code here
```

By any chance do you know what is causing this errors and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the type of plainText? I suspect it's a String. You can't copy a string to an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy `plainTextBytes`, not `plainText`:

```
   byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
   salt.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
   plainTextBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length);
```

Comment: ... make that `saltBytes`, too.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque you really solve my problem but now when I run my WPF and try to insert data I am getting error on this line:
' using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select salt From niki where user_name = @username"))
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                     salt = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                 }'

The error is connection must be valid and open. Do you have any clue where can be the problem?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov, this is a completely unrelated question, and we can't easily discuss it in the comments. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do simple hash, this bit of code may encrypt your password:

```
String GetEncryptedPassword (String prmUser, String prmPassword)
{
    // Concatenating the password and user name.
    String encryptedPassword = prmUserName + prmPassword;

    // Converting into the stream of bytes.
    Byte[] passInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedPassword);

    // Encrypting using SHA1 encryption algorithm.
    passInBytes = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(passInBytes);

    // Formatting every byte into %03d to make a fixed length 60 string.
    return passInBytes.Aggregate(String.Empty, (pass, iter) => pass += String.Format("{0:000}", iter));
}
```

This code will give you a nice encrypted hash of 60 characters. But remember that you can't regenerate your original username and password from the hash, because this is a one way algorithm. There are few more encryption algorithms in `System.Security.Cryptography` that you can use.